# Xamarin.Forms "Application.Current" under iOS is not my Application class

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I'm writing a Xamarin.Forms application using Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012.

I'm trying to exit the current content page using the following code:

```
        async void _quitButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool doQuit = await DisplayAlert("Confirm", "Are you sure you want to quit?", "yes", "no");
            if (doQuit)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
            }
        }
```

This works under Android, but on IOS, Application.Current is *not* an instance of my application class, but and instance of Xamarin.Forms.PageExtensions.EmbeddedApplication. Calling PopAsync has no effect, and in examining the Navigation object on iOS, it shows an empty navigation stack, vs the 4 pages I expect to see and do see on Android.

How do I access the correct Navigation stack under iOS to achieve the same effect of exiting the current content form?

More background:

The Application.Current property is correct (ie, an instance of my app class) for most of the application life cycle until the content page I am having problems with is rendered. This particular page is also using skiasharp and skiasharp.forms, to create an SKCanvas to render into. My suspicion is that has something to do with the page extension app class getting instanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a dumb mistake on my part.

I had created a new ViewController in unrelated iOS-specific code in something that I was experimenting with, and that was causing the App.Current static property to get overwritten.

(the experimental code was related to forcing that content page to display in landscape orientation, and at one point, I was under the impression that a custom view controller was required to achieve that on iOS under Xamarin.Forms. That is not the case, but the dead code was still executing.)

Comment: If anyone stumbles across this, it was the same for me, BUT it can be resolved by setting the (new page).Parent = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current; prior to calling the CreateViewController since I still needed that code he mentioned.  But this entry did point me to resolving it.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an ambiguous reference and you probably imported the wrong namespace into your iOS project. Try referencing the full namespace path of the Application class:

`Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current`

Comment: That is not it, the fully qualified Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current also evaluates to an instance of Xamarin.Forms.PageExtensions.EmbeddedApplication.

Comment: Note that is is not the case in the page's constructor, or even in an override of OnAppearing. In those cases, the App.Current is the correct class.